# Blog post per page setting conflicting with custom WP_Query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, pagination, query-posts

I am creating a theme, and have run into a problem with how a custom WP_Query seems to interact with the ***Blog pages show at most settings*** found under *Settings -> Reading* in the WordPress backend. I have a paged query, where - for layout reasons, I want to display 6 posts per page. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()):
    while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();?>
                        <div class="blogpost-div">
                            My blogpost goes here
                        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
else:
    _e('There are currently no posts available.', 'textdomain');
endif;

echo custom_pagination($loop);
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This works fine. However, if I have less than 6 published blog posts in my installation, this query displays no posts (Or if the next page doesen't have 6 posts, it 404s) **unless the aforementioned reading setting is also set to be limited at 6 posts**. This becomes an issue, if someone needs to install my theme on a fresh installation of WordPress, since they would then also need to adjust these settings.

**In short - it seems, that when a custom query tries to modify** `posts_per_page`**, and the total amount of posts generated by the query is less than the defined number of posts in** `posts_per_page` **the query somehow conflicts with the "Blog pages show at most settings" if these aren't set to the same value.**

Is this really intentional?

Comment: Where are you using the code? On a Page (i.e. post type `page`), e.g. at `example.com/my-page`, the homepage, a category page, or?

Comment: I am using this in my `home.php` template, my `tag.php` template, my `category.php` template and my `search.php` template.

Comment: I should add, that I use a modified version of this on everything that is not the `home.php` template - however, the problem still persists (and is alleviated by adjusting the reading settings). My go-to workaround at this point, is to simply not use `posts_per_page` in the query at all, and instead let the reading settings dictate the amount of posts that the query will show, but this is less than ideal. I'm assuming that the parameter exists in the first place, so that it can be used to hard-code the kind of behaviour that I am looking for - it just seems to not be the case for some reason?

Comment: You can't paginate custom/secondary loop on archive/non-singular pages, e.g. a category page and search results pages, unless if you use a different query string like `page_num`, because the main query uses the `paged` query string, so if your custom loop has more pages than the main query, then for example, going to page #3 of your loop will result in the main query throwing a `404` error, unless the main query had 3 or more pages of results. And if you're just trying to modify the main query, use the `pre_get_posts` hook and not making the custom loop.

Comment: My main query, is this custom query on all the archive pages - which means that there is no secondary query in any of the templates. It works. It just doesen't work if there are less posts than what the `posts_per_page` is set to **if the reading settings aren't aligned** - if they are, there are no problems at all. Seems very weird to me.

Comment: The main query is referenced by the global `$wp_query` variable and is the one you display using the standard loop - `while ( have_posts() ) ...`, but that `$loop = new WP_Query()` and `while ( $loop->have_posts() )` is a secondary/custom loop. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) for details.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, however paginating a custom wp_query loop in this way seems to work fine in both archive and search templates. As I wrote above, if I align the reading settings with the value of my custom `posts_per_page` attribute, there are absolutely no errors I can produce, which is what my original post is about.

Comment: Yes, it works so long as the custom query has **less than or same number of** pages as the main query. But on singular pages, it should always work. And regarding that original post, try suppressing filters by adding `'suppress_filters' => true` to your query args and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I see what you are saying - thanks for the help!